# loading binary code to hardware

Tags: assembly

i recently studying detail working of software.so learning the pc which is build on Altair 8800 and to run it they used BASIC language to created an interpreter to translate the program to the machine code based on the processor instruction set. They feed the interpreter in binary format code using tapes.

- But later how they manage to install the interpreter are compiler
  directly to the hardware as they only understand machine code?
- Consider i have a processor and based on the instruction set i have
  developed an interpreter in assembly language(using opcode)    again
  i need to convert them to machine code but how to feed then    into
  the processor memory ,is it using a magnetic tapes?in today's
  world it is difficult?

Comment: I think you wont get help there. Check out "retrocomputing" stackexchange site.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how you get machine code onto ROM chips.  EPROM / EEPROM chips are eraseable programmable memory, where you write with special hardware for programming the ROM.  Once you figure out what bytes you want in your ROM, you give that data to an EEPROM programming device, then socket your EEPROM into the motherboard.  In today's world, you'd probably use flash memory.

Comment: "where you write with special hardware for programming the ROM." what do you mean by that...
but still to write into that you need to convert you program (opcode) to machine code...how can we able to convert the assembly to machine and load then in there..

Comment: All the early home 8 bit computers had ROM with some kind of service firmware, very often containing BASIC interpreter as well. So that one could have been used by user to access storage devices (usually tapes, or even floppy disk drives) and load further data into RAM. How the firmware itself was created... mostly by hand on paper, not sure whether they bothered to write assembler for some other platform and cross compile, or just translated it to machine code by hand, depends on the size of the code (the ZX Spectrum ROM was 16kiB, containing whole BASIC int. including floating point!).

Comment: In todays world, if you are recreating those things, you often do that with FPGA, which can not only be programmed to work as particular simpler CPU, but IIRC you can put some small binary data into it directly while designing the other gates doing the CPU thing, so you don't need ROM chip. In case you wish, you may use some kind of EEPROM/flash ROM to connect somewhere into fixed memory area, and run that. You would have to do some of this any way, as the CPU itself without some loader can't do anything with tapes. So no need to use tapes, unless you really want to for the fun (it's NOT!).

Comment: ya great,today we use flash drive.but when i saw video of altair working it only had the instruction set in them and to load the interpreter they used a punch-card tapes.so my doubt is,
How they manage to install the interpreter directly to the hardware?
If an interpreter has been programmed in assembly language, how did it then become something that the computer could understand?
And what is a firmware?

Comment: They did knew the CPU they will use. So they could have written the original firmware either by hand on paper, or cross compile on some other, already working platform. Result of assembler is "machine code". Actually it was not that rare back then to skip "assembler" and write code directly in machine code (byte values), like for very short routines it was bearable (I still recall the instruction `RET` on Z80 CPU has value `201`). Then you had some factory producing ROM chips, which you gave them those binary data (containing machine code of interpreter), and they produced chips like that.

Comment: How they did it in the factory, whether they created the ROM image by hand, or had already some automation and were capable to read different disks/tapes... I have no idea. I have very very limited HW knowledge, but I think it was possible to "draw" the chip for lithography process, so basically you could by hand draw which values will be stored in the ROM memory after powering it on. That image was then burnt into chips. BTW, flash memory is not completely the same thing as USB flash drive, they are related (by type of memory used), but flash memory is chip/memory-like, not device-like.

Comment: For the Altair 8800 Basic in particular, Bill Gates used his university's computer to program the interpreter in 8080 assembly. He then used a cross assembler to produce 8080 machine code and punched that on the paper tape. To run it, you just loaded the tape's content into memory and jumped to the beginning of the code.

Comment: Bo Persson -
i am not sure how the cross assembler works?if they directly convert assembly to machine code why cant they apply the same to the altair interpreter.

   And Ped7g ,
on "Then you had some factory producing ROM chips, which you gave them those binary data (containing machine code of interpreter), and they produced chips like that."
but apple introduce the usage Rom for the interpreter before that how could it be implemented?

Comment: See [How was the first assembler for a new home computer platform written](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/how-was-the-first-assembler-for-a-new-home-computer-platform-written) on retrocomputing.SE.  There are a lot of details in comments and answers there about how such computers were bootstrapped.  @leaner: Use @ username to notify someone when you reply to them.

Comment: Cross assembler is written in machine code of machine where it runs, but produces machine code of target machine, as it was written like that. There's no problem to write compiler/assembler producing machine code for different CPU, as it is just producing the machine code, not running it. It's similar like writing mp3 from sound, there are some rules how mp3 binary should be, and you compress sounds and write it under such rules. Same goes with 8080 machine code, if `mov a,...` is `A8` opcode, then you write `A8` opcode, even if `A8` on current machine is invalid code (not run there, np).

Comment: and the ROM memory chip was IIRC invented before CPUs, but check wiki + history books, I don't hold these things in my head.

Comment: Cross compiling is even more popular right now. You wouldn't write a phone app directly in the phone, you use some other computer to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They feed the interpreter in binary format code using tapes.

When a CPU starts up it reads machine code instructions starting at a certain address. I don't know about the 8800 but the Altair 680 did not have RAM memory but ROM memory (which had to be bought extra!) at that address.

In the 1970s ROM memory was typically memory which was already written in the factory and could not be erased, overwritten or modified after the production. (Like a CD bought in the music store today.)

The simplest ROM you could buy for the 680 contained a program which evaluated commands received from a "terminal" (e.g. a keyboard and a screen) connected to the computer. If you typed a certain command **that program (and not the computer itself)** was loading another program from a tape into RAM.

On the 680 you could buy and install a different ROM - for example a ROM already containing a basic interpreter. In this case you didn't have to load it from tape into RAM any more.

> Consider i have a processor ... how to feed then into the processor memory

As I have written: There must be some memory attached to the CPU which already contains code which is executed when the CPU is started.

This may already be "your" code (which is often the case when using microcontrollers) or some code which is loading other code from somewhere (e.g. from a tape).

> in today's world

Modern PCs also have memory already containing some program when the computer is switched on. Oversimplified you may say that this program is then loading the operating system from the hard disk...

Comment: Related: [How was the first assembler for a new home computer platform written](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/how-was-the-first-assembler-for-a-new-home-computer-platform-written) on retrocomputing.SE.